# is $f(x)=x^4 +x^3 +x^2 +x +1$ irreducible in $R=(\mathbb Z/7\mathbb Z)[x]$?

Tags: ring-theory

is $f(x)=x^4 +x^3 +x^2 +x +1$ irreducible in $R=(\mathbb Z/7\mathbb Z)[x]$?

I know that $f(x)$ cannot be expressed as a product of degree 1 polynomial and degree 3 polynomial since it has no roots in $R$ but what about two degree 2 polynimials?

Comment: You just experiment, $(x^2 + a x + b)(x^2 + c x + d),$ all regarded mod 7. Does not take long to decide, possible or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $(X-1)(X^4 + X^3 + X^2 + X + 1) = X^5 - 1$, if $f$ wasn’t irreducible, you’d have a degree two factor $(X - α)(X - β) = X^2 - (α+β) X + αβ~$ of $X^5 - 1$ of $f$ in $ℤ/7ℤ[X]$, where $α$, $β$ and therefore $αβ$ ($∈ ℤ/7ℤ$) had to be $5$-th roots of unity. What $5$-th roots of unity are there in $ℤ/7ℤ$? What possibilities are there for $α$ and $β$? (Note that $α$ and $β$ don’t have to be elements of $ℤ/7ℤ$ a priori, but elements of some extension of $ℤ/7ℤ$.)

Comment: This is kind of sketchy. At first I thought it was the way to go, now I’m not so sure.

Comment: @Lubin. Hm, why?

Comment: @Lubin The fifth roots of unity form a group under multiplication.

Comment: if alpha and beta are in Z/7Z won't it mean that f has a root in Z/7Z?

Comment: Do not assume that they are in $ℤ/7ℤ$! Assume you have a a degree two factor $g ∈ ℤ/7ℤ[X]$ of $f$. Assume there is a ring $R$ such that $ℤ/7ℤ \subseteq R$  with elements $α, β ∈ R$ such that $g$ splits as $g = (X - α)(X - β)$. It’s okay to assume that, because $R = ℤ/7ℤ[X]/(g)$ with the natural inclusion of $ℤ/7ℤ$ has the above mentioned properties, so you can work there. You can’t say $α ∈ ℤ/7ℤ$ or $β ∈ ℤ/7ℤ$ a priori, but you can say that $α^5 - 1 = 0$ and $β^5 - 1$, because they both are roots of $g$, and therefore roots of $f$ and therefore roots of $X^5 - 1$.

Answer (score 1):

If $f=(ax^2+bx+c)(dx^2+ex+f)$ with $a,d \neq 0$ mod $7$ one can divide the first factor by $a$ to make it monic, then remultiply by $a$ to compensate. So resetting the coefficients at this point $f=(x^2+bx+c)(dx^2+ex+f).$  [these are "reset" $d,e,f$] Then the second factor is also monic to make the coefficient of $x^4$ in the product match that of $f.$ So we have
$$f=(x^2+bx+c)(x^2+ex+f).$$
Now we have $cf=1$ so that $c,f$ make one of the pairs (in either order) $(1,1),\ (2,4),\ (3,5),\ (6,6).$ We also have $b+e=1$ so that $b,e$ make up one of the pairs $(0,1),\ (2,6),\ (3,5),\ (4,4).$ Now the coefficient of $x^2$ in the product is $(c+f)+(be).$ The values of $c+f$ are $1,2,5,6,$ while the values of $be$ are $0,1,2,5.$ So to get the coefficient of $x^2$ to be $1$ we need a sum of $1$ mod $7$ using one term from the first list and one from the second. The only choice is $c+f=6,\ be=2.$ This leads to $(c,f)=(2,4)$ [without loss] and to $(b,e)=(4,4).$ But then the product of the two factors becomes $x^4+8x^3+22x^2+24x+8,$ which has all coeffients $1$ mod $7$ except that of $x^1$ which happens to come out $3$ mod $7.$

*Added note to explain a comment below:* The expansion of $(x^2+bx+c)(x^2+ex+f)$ is
$$x^4+(b+e)x^3+(c+f+be)x^2+(bf+ce)x+cf.$$
So although true that $bf+ce=1,$ it is also true that the simpler relation $b+e=1$ must hold, in order that this product should match $f$ which has all coefficients $1$ mod $7.$
The above argument works by assuming the cubic and constant coefficients are $1$ to get relations separately between $b,e$ versus $c,f$ and then putting these into the $x^2$ coefficient, since that has a simple expression in terms of sum/products from $b,e$ and $c,f.$ The last thing one would try to match would be the coefficient $bf+ce$ of the power $x^1,$ and that gives what goes wrong in this case since it cannot be made $1$ after the other coefficients of $f$ have been matched.

Comment: it is actually bf+ce = 1 and not b+e=1

Comment: The coefficient of $x^3$ is $b+e$ so that has to be $1.$ I used that here since it only mentions $b,e$ and the other equation $cf=1$ from comparing constant terms only mentions $c,f$. With this approach, two separate expressions involving $b,e$ or $c,f$ respectively add up to give the $x^2$ coefficient.

Comment: Nathan: In some ways, the answer of k.stm is simpler, in that it doesn't need to get into the specifics of computing all the coefficients. (Maybe if you follow that answer it should be the selected one for this question...)

Comment: Okay, as you wish.